# Set up Git-User in Aptana

Tags: git

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 Standalone as IDE. As GIT client, I've been using eGit for quite a while, but I didn't like the menus and options there too much.

So, I wanted to give the build-in git client a chance. I like it way better, but my problem is that after I removed `eGit` my username is displayed as **unknown** on all commits I make.

I didn't change anything in my options tho, I still have entries in

```
Window -> preferences -> Git -> Configuration -> User Settings

email: myname@myaddress.net
name: thisShouldBeUsedForCommitsRight
```

but it seems like the git client completely ignores those values.

How and where do I set up git username & email for Aptana's integrated git client?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```